# Perturbative RG approach

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, perturbation-theory

I'm currently trying to understand Shankar's review (1994) on perturbative RG, and I'm slightly confused above the field theory approach of the $\phi^4$ theory (section II.D). Indeed, what Shankar does is compute the 4-point **connected** correlation function $\Gamma(4,3,2,1)$ up to some order of loops (or actually some order of $u_0$ to be precise). However what I don't understand is why isn't the following diagram considered in the calculation?

Indeed, in the modern approach (II.C), this diagram would have zero contribution, since the internal legs are integrated over fast modes $d\Lambda$, while the external legs are slow modes. However, whe calculating $\Gamma(4321)$, it seems that internal legs are integrated over all modes $\le \Lambda$, and the external legs also satisfy $\le \Lambda$.

[image: Feynman]

**EDIT**. As commented, the effective interaction only cares about 1-particle irreducible diagrams. A pretty good intro (at least for me) can be found in Negele and Orland's *Quantum Many-particle systems* Chapter 2.4.

Comment: I haven’t got his review, but $\Gamma$ usually stands for the 1PI correlation function.

Comment: As already pointed out in the previous comment, the diagram you drew is not 1PI irreducible, and therefore should not be included in your calculation of effective interaction.